# Ruby Dir.glob on windows network share

Tags: ruby, windows, glob, dir

I would like to get a simple list of files with Dir.glob on a windows machine, where the filter would be something like `//hostname/share/folder/*.zip`.

The only thing that works with glob on windows is a local path: `c:/folder/*.zip`

I tried different ways, but no luck so far:

```
\\\\hostname\\share\\folder\\*.zip
\\hostname\share\folder\*.zip
//hostname/share/folder/*.zip 
z:/folder/*.zip    # z: would be a network drive
```

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7-p352 and tried on different windows platforms.

Comment: Can you try Ruby 1.9.3-p194? Several issues associated with Windows did considerably improve on 1.9.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a working sample on Windows7 and Ruby 1.9.3

```
def get_files(path)
  Dir.glob("#{path}/**/*").each {|e|puts e}
end

list_files("//USER-PC/SHARE/MAP")
```

Answer (score 2):

At least it is possible, I made it in the past.

To get `c:\usr\*` on `hostname` I use:

```
Dir['\\\\hostname/c$/usr/*']
```

The combination of

- `'` and four `\`
- `/` as separator (not for the host)
- `c$` instead `c:`

was important for my success.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input. I'm sorry to tell you that the problem was less ruby related than a windows issue. When running through the ruby console it all worked well, the problem was that I had a mongrel service installed which was using the local system account which seems impossible to convice to connect properly to a network share. It works now straight away with a normal account.